# COPY can only be used in cqlsh, and so I can't use it as a CQL command in Java. Is there a similar way to import a CSV into a table?

Tags: java, csv, file-io, cassandra, cql

I have a CSV text file that I want to use to fill a table in my keyspace (using Java).

I tried using the COPY command, but I just realized that the COPY command is not an actual CQL command: it's something that can only be run with the cqlsh shell.

What I tried to do:

```
session.execute("COPY table(Column1,Column2,Column3) 
                 FROM ('textfile.txt') 
                 WITH DELIMITER='\t'");
```

(And the code before that if you want it for context):

```
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
    Session session = cluster.connect( );
    session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};";);
    session.execute("USE test");
    session.execute("CREATE TABLE table(Column1 text, Column2 text, Column3 text, PRIMARY KEY(Column1))");
```

And the main error message I have is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:0 no viable
>   alternative at input 'COPY' ([COPY]...)

Which I googled, and found out that you can only use COPY through cqlsh.

Is there another way to easily import a CSV into a keyspace? One that I'll be able to use through CQL commands in Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that 'copy' is a cqlsh (shell) command rather than a CQL (protocol) command. Here are the relevant docs which explain which apply in each case:

- [cqlsh commands](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCommandsTOC.html)
- [CQL commands](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlCommandsTOC.html)

To import from a CSV file within your Java app you would need to write it yourself. One popular tool is the [cassandraloader](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader) which is written in Java. There may be other source code snippets you could learn from as well.